# Manipulate the resolveinfo object in apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server and I have a special case where I need to change the input query programmatically inside the resolver.

Ex:
Let say I get a graphQL-query that looks like this:

```
query {
  Car {
    brand
    color
  } 
}
```

When this code comes to my resolver I want to change the resolverInfo parameter object to add an extra field inside the query. To something like this:

```
query {
  Car {
    id    //  <--- This is the new field
    brand
    color
  } 
}
```

Is this something that could be done easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that you would want to do, even if it were possible.

The whole point of GraphQL is that the client is only requesting the data that it needs. If it did not request a field, then it is on the client to deal with that, not you.

That is to say, you are not responsible for resolving fields that the client did not request.

Comment: Well, the reason I want to do this is that I need the extra field in a sub resolver. And when I then have the ID of the car I can do a DB-call (to another DB/Backend which I'm using with that ID). I do not want to return the ID to the client. Just to have the ID available in a sub resolver.

Comment: @Christian Ah, I see what your question is now. The good news is that you can still do that regardless -- you don't actually have to actually modify the incoming query (which is not advisable nor possible) to get the data that you need passed down to a sub resolver. That's what the `parent` argument in your resolver function is for! I could explain it further, but honestly, this article does a great job: https://moonhighway.com/the-parent-argument

Comment: @Christian the basic idea is that whatever you resolve in the top/parent resolver can be made available through the `parent` argument in the sub/child resolver.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My reason for wanting to edit the input is due to a framework I use that passes inn the resolverInfo to get exactly what the client ask for. If I change the resolverInfo and add the ID I only have to do 1 call to the DB (instead of 2).  I managed to do it, but I feel that this is a hack and I have no guarantees that it will work in later releases of Apollo

Comment: @Christian If you are worried about making multiple trips to the DB due to GraphQL's resolver behavior/tendencies for N+1 query issues, you may want to look at the Dataloader pattern.

Comment: @Christian I have a suspicion this is going to come in handy: https://github.com/graphql/dataloader

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look into dataloader. Looks pretty good if it can gather queries within a "tick" and batch load it.

Comment: @Christian Exactly, that is the idea.